# Is there a nodejs complete webserver package, serving dynamic content?

Tags: node.js, webserver

I am building my first nodejs-backed site. Is there a single-drop package to handle:
a) HTTP requests and responses
b) Dynamic content creation?

Something similar to JSP framework or PHP's CodeIgniter, just a single-drop standard encapsulation of standard web-server operations, using Nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

Express as a cli tool call `express` which does that.
It is quite useful. To get it

```
sudo npm install express -g
```

And then

```
express MyAppFolder
```

Comment: Also express has a quite good documentation: http://expressjs.com/ and is also found on github https://github.com/visionmedia/express

Comment: Well the doc was amazing until this weekend, the new doc lack a shit lot of thing, you may to have to look in to the example folder a bit. I hope this because it is a work in progress.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Just realised the new site.